# Text input show suggestions per word

Tags: html

I can enable suggestions on an input by using:

`<datalist id="prompt_suggestions"></datalist>`

And filling it up with an array of options.

But it only works for the whole input.

I'm using this to input various words (tags).

I would want each word to trigger the suggestions.

Right now it only triggers for the whole thing.

So it ignores suggestions after the first word.

Is it possible to make it "per word" ?